# Pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, bigint

```
scala> (1,5) == BigInt(12) /% 7
res3: Boolean = true

scala> BigInt(12) /% 7 match {
 | case (1,5) => true
 | }

<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(1)
required: scala.math.BigInt
          case (1,5) => true
                ^
```

Can someone perhaps explain me how to pattern match here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`match` is more specific than equality; you can't just be equal, you must also have the same type.

In this case, `BigInt` is not a case class and does not have an `unapply` method in its companion object, so you can't match on it directly.  The best you could do is

```
  BigInt(12) /% 7 match {
    case (a: BigInt,b: BigInt) if (a==1 && b==5) => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

or some variant thereof (e.g. `case ab if (ab == (1,5)) =>`).

Alternatively, you could create an object with an unapply method of appropriate type:

```
object IntBig { def unapply(b: BigInt) = Option(b.toInt) }

scala> BigInt(12) /% 7 match { case (IntBig(1), IntBig(5)) => true; case _ => false }
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Binding to variables and a guard is what I did. I just thaught it could perhaps be done a little better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`1` and `5` are `Int` types. The pattern match is expecting a `scala.math.BigInt`. So, give it that by declaring a couple of vals for one and five.

```
scala> val OneBig = BigInt(1)
oneBig: scala.math.BigInt = 1

scala> val FiveBig = BigInt(5)
fiveBig: scala.math.BigInt = 5

scala> BigInt(12) /% 7 match {
     | case (OneBig, FiveBig) => true
     | }
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: This doesn't work! `oneBig` and `fiveBig` in the pattern are new variables unrelated to the ones defined before. This can be changed by naming them with a capital letter (`OneBig` and `FiveBig`) or by surrounding the names in backticks.

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about that. For those interested see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479474/scala-pattern-matching-with-lowercase-variable-name or page 317 of the stairway book.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `1` and `5` returned by `/%` are `BigInt`s and so don't match literal `Int`s even though `equals` method (called by `==`) returns true. This works but is a bit inelegant:

```
scala> BigInt(12) /% 7 match { case (x, y) if x == 1 && y == 5 => true }
res3: Boolean = true
```