# Scala.swing GUI -- How to separate multiple reaction cases

Tags: swing, scala, user-interface, listener, buttonclick

I am currently in the process of turning a sudoku solving program into a GUI with scala.swing and running into some trouble with the use of different functions. That is to say, I have a function for completely solving the puzzle, another for offering a hint entry, and another that will reset the grid. The interface consists of 81 individual ComboBox'es (see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcT7p.png) and three buttons that perform said functions. **My problem** is that, while the separate reactions/cases involved reference specifically which buttons/functions to listen to, any button will incite all of the functions. My code for each of the listeners/buttons looks something like the following

```
listenTo(solve,comb11,comb12,comb13,comb14,comb15,comb16,comb17,comb18,comb19,comb21,comb22,comb23,comb24,comb25,comb26,comb27,comb28,comb29,comb31,comb32,comb33,comb34,comb35,comb36,comb37,comb38,comb39,comb41,comb42,comb43,comb44,comb45,comb46,comb47,comb48,comb49,comb51,comb52,comb53,comb54,comb55,comb56,comb57,comb58,comb59,comb61,comb62,comb63,comb64,comb65,comb66,comb67,comb68,comb69,comb71,comb72,comb73,comb74,comb75,comb76,comb77,comb78,comb79,comb81,comb82,comb83,comb84,comb85,comb86,comb87,comb88,comb89,comb91,comb92,comb93,comb94,comb95,comb96,comb97,comb98,comb99)
  reactions += {
    case ButtonClicked(solve) =>
    ...[working code for solve function]...
  }
```

(The 'comb##'s are the exhaustive 81 ComboBoxes and the 'solve' is the button that solves the whole puzzle.) If I get rid of all but one of the listener/reaction blocks of code, clicking the remaining button works perfectly. If I try to include two or all of the listener/reaction code blocks, then every button causes ALL functions to be performed, which is clearly confusing and undesirable.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your problem. But if you use [*lower case names* in pattern matching extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479474/scala-pattern-matching-with-lowercase-variable-name), these are fresh variables, and have nothing to do with values of the same name defined elsewhere. So to react to the `solve` button, you need to match against the value `solve` which you can do by putting it in back ticks:

```
listenTo(allMyButtons: _*)
reactions += {
  case ButtonClicked(`solve`) =>  // note the back ticks!
  ...[working code for solve function]...
}
```

Otherwise, why don't you just keep each reaction with each combo box?

```
val combos = Vector.tabulate(81) { i =>
  new ComboBox(1 to 9) {
    listenTo(this)
    reactions += {
      case ButtonClicked(_) =>
        ... // not important to check the button - we only listen to one!
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a shorter way of defining the reaction to a pressed button.

```
import swing.{MainFrame, FlowPanel, Button}

val frame = new MainFrame {
  contents = new FlowPanel {
    contents += Button("solve")(println("solve"))
  }
  visible = true
}
```