# Play framework scala template with case statement on enumeration

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this scala template and want to use a case statement to render different html based on a matching enum value.

My template looks like this:

```
@(tagStatus: String)

 try {
   TagStatus.withName(tagStatus) match {
         case TagStatus.deployed => {<span class="label label-success">@tagStatus</span>}
         case TagStatus.deployedPartially => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
         case TagStatus.deployedWithProblems => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
     }
 } catch {
    {<span class="label label-important">??</span>}
 }
```

The enum looks something like this:

```
object TagStatus extends Enumeration{
   val deployed = Value("deployed")
   val deployedWithProblems = Value("deployed_with_problems")
   val deployedPartially = Value("deployed_partially")     
}
```

When i run this i get:

```
Compilation error
')' expected but 'case' found.
In C:\...\statusTag.scala.html at line 8.
5        case TagStatus.deployed => {<span class="label label-success">@tagStatus</span>}
6        case TagStatus.deployedPartially => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
7        case TagStatus.deployedWithProblems => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
8    } 
9 } catch {
10    {<span class="label label-important">??</span>}
11 }
```

I have not idea what is meant by this error message.

What am i missing in order to get this simple code snippet to compile?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toString is not compatible with match so convert the String to the enum using `withName`

You can do it like this - I am not quite sure of the Play syntax:

```
TagsStatus.withName(tagStatus) match {
  case TagStatus.deployed => {<span class="label label-success">@tagStatus</span>}
  case TagStatus.deployedPartially => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
  case TagStatus.deployedWithProblems => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
  case _ => {<span class="label label-important">??</span>}
}
```

BTW there is a common related issue concerning [Scala pattern matching with lower case variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479474/scala-pattern-matching-with-lowercase-variable-name?lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use try here, just the wild card in you match (see: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases).

```
@(tagStatus: String)

@tagStatus match {
    case TagStatus.deployed.toString => {<span class="label label-success">@tagStatus</span>}
    case TagStatus.deployedPartially.toString => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
    case TagStatus.deployedWithProblems.toString => {<span class="label label-important">@tagStatus</span>}
    case _ => {<span class="label label-important">??</span>}
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error: stable identifier required, but models.TagStatus.notReadyForDeployment.toString found. It works if i hardcode the strings in the match case statement but that way i would not be DRY any more.

Comment: Unlike in plain Scala, the output of each case (after the => symbol) has to be wrapped in {}, otherwise you get a "'case' expected but identifier found" error.