# Scala read two integers at the same time error

Tags: scala

I have the following code for reading 2 integers:

```
Array(N, Q) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

For this, I am getting the following error:

```
error: value update is not a member of object Array
```

If I do

```
val Array(N, Q) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt)
```

I get:

```
error: not found: value N
```

If I declare them before:

```
val N, Q
```

I get:

```
!error: '=' expected but ';' found.
```

So how can I read these integers at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't capitalize the variable names.

```
scala> val Array(n, q) = Array(1, 2)
n: Int = 1
q: Int = 2
```

Scala pattern matching special-cases identifiers starting with capital letters.

Related questions:

- [How to pattern match into an uppercase variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636972/how-to-pattern-match-into-an-uppercase-variable)
- [Scala syntax strangeness with :: and requiring lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671616/scala-syntax-strangeness-with-and-requiring-lower-case/)

Comment: or back-tick them to indicate they're variables and not pattern-matchers (`val Array(\`N\`, \`Q\`) = ...`)